# Can anyone give me an idea about using couchdb in an android application?

Tags: android, sqlite, couchdb

I have used SQLite and phpmyadmin to store data from amy android application. i want to use couchdb.But i have no idea about couch db. And does couch db require Knowledge of php?Please can anyone give me some idea about couch db?

Answer (score 0):

You can access CouchDb using RESTful HTTP calls. You can access it from Java using an HTTP client, or use an existing library for it. You can get more info on Couch's API [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API). You can find the existing Java libraries for Couch [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Java). Looks like [DroidCouch](http://github.com/sig/DroidCouch/) might be best for you.